# How to create a single pdf from multiple html using pdfreactor

Tags: java, java-11, pdf-reactor

In my code I have a dynamic list of html strings and want to create a single pdf out of it using pdfreactor.
The `configuration.setMergeDocuments` method only accepts pdf files as input, not html.
What is the best way to get a single pdf out of multiple html strings using pdfreactor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted support. Unfortunately there is no way (yet) to create a PDF from multiple HTMLs. You have to create all PDFs separately and then use [a workaround](https://support.realobjects.com/support/solutions/articles/7000018262-can-i-merge-a-set-of-existing-pdfs-without-converting-an-additional-html-) with an empty HTML and the overlay option to merge the previously created PDFs.